# An attempt to switch to a doublescan X11 modeline fails with "Configure crtc 0 failed"

Tags: xorg, display, xrandr, resolution

I have a modern `1920x1200` LED display, capable of up to 96 kHz `HorizSync`, up to 76 Hz `VertRefresh`, and up to 205 MHz pixel clock.

Apart from its native resolution, the display can also run in `1600x1200` (4:3) resolution at 75 Hz:

```
  1600x1200 (0xa1) 202.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  93.75KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  75.00Hz
```

Now, I'm trying to switch it to a `800x600` doublescan mode equivalent to the above `1600x1200` mode (at 75 Hz, too; all modelines taken from [here](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Modeline_Database)):

```bsh
xrandr --newmode "800x600d" 101.25 800 832 928 1080 600 600 602 625 DoubleScan +HSync +VSync
xrandr --addmode DP1 800x600d
```

The resulting video mode gets added successfully and is clearly visible in the output of `xrandr`:

```
  800x600d (0x1f7) 101.250MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   800 start  832 end  928 total 1080 skew    0 clock  93.75KHz
        v: height  600 start  600 end  602 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
```

But once I attempt to switch to the new mode, I immediately receive an error:

```bsh
# Mode by name
$ xrandr --output DP1 --mode 800x600d
xrandr: cannot find mode 800x600d

# Mode by id
$ xrandr --output DP1 --mode 0x1f7
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

Are modern graphics cards no longer able to run in a doublescan mode?
Or should I blame my display?

Comment: While the hardware may actually support it, it also needs support by the X driver, and probably no one has bothered with this in decades. Details depend on your graphic card and X driver, which you didn't tell us about, but patching the X driver and recompiling X is always an option. You may even send the patch upstream if it works. Double scan on a DP port may also need different hardware settings compared to VGA double scan.

Comment: @dirkt Thank you for your comment. I tested on a relatively modern (2 years old) integrated Intel graphics card, but my primary goal was to revive old hardware (3Dfx Voodoo 4 and Matrox MGA G450) and play with custom 16:10 and doublescan modes (over a VGA cable). Haven't tested doublescan with those ancient cards, though: with modern Mesa versions they're slow, and Mesa dropped support for DRI v1 since version 8, so I'm yet to find a suitable Linux distribution. Could you please expand a bit on patching an X11 driver module? How is it different from manually adding a `ModeLine` via `xrandr`?

Comment: @dirkt And what is a potential difference (from the software perspective) between an analog VGA signal and a digital DP signal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer, and quick one:

Graphics cards have evolved from the legacy model based on a CRTC (CRT controller) that started out as an [6845](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_6845), with an index and data register to change internal registers, to something completely different in major graphics hardware lines (Intel, Nvidia, ATI/AMD, and others as well).

In legacy VGA it was a sort-of agreed bit in one of the registers. Because legacy VGA is **still** supported by basically all graphic cards, that's still there. But in particular the circuitry to drive digital outputs has moved, so you really really need the exact model of the graphics card, and you need to dig up a datasheet to be sure if it is supported or not. Sometimes a datasheet of a similar model will help, but you need to experiment.

E.g. have a look at the [Intel G35](https://www.x.org/docs/intel/VOL_3_display_registers.pdf) datasheet (which is already ancient), and you'll see two "display pipelines" in section 2.7, but the legacy double scan in register `CR09`.

If you want to revive old hardware with VGA out, chances are it will work right out of the box, if you can fine a suitable X version with a suitable driver for the card (but even the VESA driver might do, not sure if it does double scan, though).

Adding a `ModeLine` via `xrandr` with double scan basically just sets a flag in the modeline data structure. The driver will need to interpret this flag, and use it set up the registers correctly, and that (as e.g. the datasheet above shows) depends very much on the hardware.